# Transcribing MP3s using Speech to Text software?

Tags: speech-to-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transcript creator OR Speech to text](https://superuser.com/questions/10558/transcript-creator-or-speech-to-text)

I’ve got a lot of speech audio in WMA format and I’d like to machine transcribe it – even if the transcription is not 100% accurate, I think it could help quite a bit as an “index” to some of the audio. Is there already an app that can do this for me?