# How to transcribe audio from a mp4 file to text?

Tags: audio, speech-to-text, transcription

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transcript creator OR Speech to text](https://superuser.com/questions/10558/transcript-creator-or-speech-to-text)

I would like to transcribe audio to text. I have an english video in mp4 and I would like to transcribe it.

If you know of any free Windows, Mac or Iphone application, please let me know.