# Automatically convert video to text?

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-to-text, transcription

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transcript creator OR Speech to text](https://superuser.com/questions/10558/transcript-creator-or-speech-to-text)

Are there any tools (preferably free/open source) that will automatically transcribe what's spoken in a video in to text?  YouTube has this feature, and I would find a similar tool very handy for my Windows desktop & Mac laptop.

Comment: to be highly effective the software has to be trained.  there are pretty good solutions around, but this question has been asked on this forum before.